# Cannot resolve symbol 'gestures'

Tags: android, gesture

I have a OnGesturePerformed listener, a bunch of associated code, everything seems to work fine with the exception of this line:

```
private GestureLibrary gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, android.R.raw.gestures);
```

It tells me that the symbol gestures cannot be resolved. Tried various imports, does anyone know if there is a quick fix?

EDIT

Also tried:
   com.package_name.R.raw.gestures

This time R cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in [`android.R.raw`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.raw.html). You should import `R.raw.yourRawFile` from your own R file instead. Also make sure that you don't have any errors (if the file has a correct name).